# 2 RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect everything to `a.php`. And `baba` to `b.php`.

I did the following:

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !a.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !baba
RewriteRule .* a.php

RewriteRule baba b.php
```

a.php : `<?php echo 'a.php'; ?>`
b.php : `<?php echo 'b.php'; ?>`

But baba redirect to a.php too.

So I modified line 4 in htaccess to: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^!baba`

And now baba redirect to b.php but everything else gives a `Not found` error.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite engine loops until the URI going into the engine is the same coming out. The reason why `baba` is going to `a.php` is because it first gets rewritten to `b.php`, then when the engine loops, `b.php` gets rewritten to `a.php`. You can fix this by adding an additional condition to the first rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !a.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !b.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !baba
RewriteRule .* a.php

RewriteRule baba b.php
```

So `b.php` won't get rewritten to `a.php`

Comment: Thanks a lot! 2 days I've been struggling with that!

Answer (score 1):

You can separate rules for handling different types of links.

In each block you can put as many `RewriteCond` directives as you want, but each block should be closed by `RewriteRule` directive. Because RewriteCond only tells when rewrite, but rewrite itself is done in RewriteRule.

And in your first block you should check both that it is `!baba` and `!b.php`